# Unable to fetch FireBase Database into recyclerView

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I was unable to populate so I used FireBaseRecycleroption but still no output.

I have firebase database hoe to add them into recyclerview.

Why am I not able to view the data in recycler view

I found no error but still I was unable to get database kindly do help me.

> IncomeFragement.java

```
    public class IncomeFragment extends Fragment {
        
            //Firebase database
        
            private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
            private DatabaseReference mIncomeDatabase;
        
            //Recycler View
        
            private RecyclerView recyclerView;
            IncomeAdapter adapter;
        
        
            private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
            private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
        
        
            private String mParam1;
            private String mParam2;
        
        
            public static IncomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
                IncomeFragment fragment = new IncomeFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
                args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                if (getArguments() != null) {
                    mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                    mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        
                }
        
            }
        
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
                // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                View myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_income, container, false);
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                FirebaseUser mUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                String UID=mUser.getUid();
                mIncomeDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("IncomeDatabase").child(UID);
                recyclerView=myview.findViewById(R.id.recycler_income);
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        
                layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
                layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        
                FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Data> options =
                        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Data>()
                                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("IncomeDatabase"), Data.class)
                                .build();
        
                adapter=new IncomeAdapter(options);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        
                return myview;
        
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                adapter.startListening();
        
        
            }
        
        
            @Override
            public void onStop() {
                super.onStop();
                adapter.stopListening();
            }
            
        }
```

> Income adapter

```
public class IncomeAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data,IncomeAdapter.myViewHolder>

{
    public IncomeAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Data> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Data model) {
        holder.type.setText(model.getType());
        holder.note.setText(model.getNote());
        holder.amount.setText(model.getAmount());


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_income,parent,false);
        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder

    {
        TextView amount, type, note;

        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            type=itemView.findViewById(R.id.type_text_income);
            note=itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_text_income);
            amount=itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount_text_income);
        }
    }

}
```

> Data.java

```
public class Data {
    
         private int amount;
         private String type;
         private String note;
    
    
        public Data() {
        }
    
        public Data (int amount, String s, String type, String note, String id) {
            this.amount = amount;
            this.type = type;
            this.note = note;
    
        }
    
    
        public int getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }
    
        public void setAmount(int amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
        }
    
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
    
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    
        public String getNote() {
            return note;
        }
    
        public void setNote(String note) {
            this.note = note;
        }

}
```

> Jason File

```
"IncomeData" : {
    "GEyh5uOMkhQa0mCnp9oAG6W3qxD3" : {
      "-MSk7WggCS5eNG-8UNgl" : {
        "amount" : 5000,
        "date" : "Feb 5, 2021",
        "id" : "-MSk7WggCS5eNG-8UNgl",
        "note" : "I got salary",
        "type" : "Salary"
      },
      "-MSk7uXOANF6Q9QQ4Mml" : {
        "amount" : 10000,
        "date" : "Feb 5, 2021",
        "id" : "-MSk7uXOANF6Q9QQ4Mml",
        "note" : "Tesla stocks trade",
        "type" : "Dividends"
      }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: I've edited. Kindly do help me

Comment: If you try to log `model.getType()` inside `onBindViewHolder` is something printed out in the logcat?